# Github page build failed: Unknown tag error

Tags: github-pages

I have a problem with building Github page.

It is said that `'Your site is having problems building: The tag set on line 180 in Web_Optimizaion/node_modules/nunjucks/CHANGELOG.md is not a recognized Liquid tag. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-unknown-tag-error/.'`

I didn't make this error. It is just node_modules and I used it before but it was okay. Can you help me how I edit it?

Thanks,

This is the what happens: 
https://github.com/leiachung41/leiachung41.github.io/blob/master/Web_Optimizaion/node_modules/nunjucks/CHANGELOG.md

Answer (score 1):

This is line 180:

```
* Add support for `{% set %}` block assignments as in jinja2. Thanks Daniele
  Rapagnani. Merge of [#656](https://github.com/mozilla/nunjucks/pull/656)
```

My guess is that the `{% set %}` bit is being parsed as Liquid. Is this what you intended? If not, you probably want to use the `raw` tag:

```
{% raw %}{% set %}{% endraw %}
```

You could also exclude the whole file from Jekyll processing by adding this to your `_config.yml` file:

```
exclude: ['Web_Optimizaion/node_modules/nunjucks/CHANGELOG.md']
```

More info [here](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/257).